# Updating in Play Store not working

Tags: android, google-play

I just updated my app in Play Store.
I've waited few hours and I can see the changes in PlayStore.
Version of my app in PlayStore is now 1.2.3

It works well when I don't have the app installed in my cell.
But when I have the v1.2.2 in my cell, PlayStore only gives me the option to open app, I don't see the button "Update", so I have to uninstall and reinstall to have the latest version, it is quite confusing.

Anyone know why it happens?

Comment: This is not really related to programming. Anyways, sometimes it takes time until phone gets notified it can update the app. I noticed it myself, but it always gets updated later.

Comment: It is related because the problem might be in code unless it is a Google Play Bug.

Comment: Wait until a day has passed since you updated the app, then check again. It can take time.